# How do I set a timeout for a google translation?

Tags: go, google-translate

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples/translate-text-with-model?hl=zh-cn#translate_text_with_model-go

[image]
I'm using the example in the link.When I turn off the proxy.It seems to take 30s to time out.How do I set the timeout duration?And is there an example?

Replace 'context.Background()' with 'context.WithTimeout()' seems doesn't work.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("start..")
    t := "The Go Gopher is cute"
    now := time.Now()
    r, err := translateTextWithModel("zh-CN", t, "nmt")
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(now).Milliseconds(), "ms")
    fmt.Println(t, "-->", r)
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
    fmt.Println("end..")
}
```

```
func translateTextWithModel(targetLanguage, text, model string) (string, error) {
    // targetLanguage := "ja"
    // text := "The Go Gopher is cute"
    // model := "nmt"

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
    defer cancel()

    lang, err := language.Parse(targetLanguage)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("language.Parse: %v", err)
    }

    client, err := translate.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("translate.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    resp, err := client.Translate(ctx, []string{text}, lang, &translate.Options{
        Model: model, // Either "nmt" or "base".
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Translate: %v", err)
    }
    if len(resp) == 0 {
        return "", nil
    }
    return resp[0].Text, nil
}
```

When turning off the proxy,sometimes like.

[image]

Comment: Show your code with the context with timeout

Comment: It looks like the authentication process does‘t use the context with timeout.@TiagoPeczenyj

Comment: If it is the case, open an  issue on the project

Answer (score -1):

As I see the library provides possibility to change settings by providing options into constructor function `translate.NewClient(ctx context.Context, opts ...option.ClientOption)`.

You can try to change `http.Client` timeout by creating new one:

```golang
// timeout that you need to set
httpClientTimeout := time.Minute * 5

// create http client with custom timeout
httpClient := &http.Client{
        Timeout: httpClientTimeout,
}

// inject new http client into translate client
client, err := translate.NewClient(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("translate.NewClient: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()
```

Hope it helpful.

Source [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/option#WithHTTPClient)

Comment: I have tried this method but it doesn't seem to work.